# Twitter JSON call only works on homepage

Tags: javascript, json, api, twitter

I am displaying a single tweet on my website JSON, the twitter API and Javascript. The tweet displays on my homepage but it does not on any subpages. On the subpages I am getting a 401 (unauthorized) error on the JSON call. Is there a way to fix this? Here is my script:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.tweets = function(options) {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        var defaults = {
            tweets: 1,
            before: "<span>",
            after: "</span>"
        };
        var optionsWithDefaults = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            $.getJSON('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name='+optionsWithDefaults.username+'&count=' + optionsWithDefaults.tweets,
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, tweet) {
                        if(tweet.text !== undefined) {
                            $(obj).append(optionsWithDefaults.before+tweet.text+optionsWithDefaults.after);
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what is different between the pages.  Is jQuery actually included on all pages? Are you passing in the proper options on the other pages?

Comment: There isn't anything different between the pages. Yes, jQuery is included on all pages. The options aren't changed between pages because the script is being called in the footer which is the same on every page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a `401 Unauthorized` HTTP error from the Twitter API it means you're trying to access some part of the API that requires user authentication (see [Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses)).

Since you haven't specified what's different in the other pages I presume you're trying to request something different like search for example. For those kind of requests you need to be authorized. To learn more about how to authorize a user I suggest you to take a look at [Implementing Sign in with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter).

Comment: Nothing is different. The only thing that is happening on any page is the display of the most recent tweet. There is not search or anything else API related. There isn't anything that should require authorization.

Comment: @user715564 Why not use the [Embedded Timelines](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines) then?

Comment: Because I don't want the ui that comes with the embedded timelines. All I need to do is display the text of a tweet.